# Using Linq when using a SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, linq, sqldatareader

With the following code is there a way that it can be used with a linq expression ?

```
IList sqlResults = new List<sqlResult>();
myConnection.Open();
using (SqlDataReader reader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
        sqlResults.Add(new sqlResult(reader));
   }
}
myConnection.Close();
```

I have tried the following but SQLDataReader doesnt appear to have the linq Select method

```
IList sqlResults = new List<sqlResult>();
myConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader= oCmd.ExecuteReader();
{
    sqlResults = reader.Select(r => new sqlResult(r));
}
myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: `reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(r = > new { Something = (SomeTypeFXString)r["Something"] } ).ToList()` ... but seriously, use some micro ORM like Dapper

Comment: what is `sqlResult` here? is it a POCO that looks like your columns? if so, indeed: this is a perfect case for Dapper - much saner code; example: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#execute-a-query-and-map-the-results-to-a-strongly-typed-list